# Swift, функция: дождаться получения данных прежде чем вернуть результат

Tags: swift, асинхронность

Есть глупая проблема, которую я не могу решить. У меня имеется функция, которая получив входной параметр обрабатывает его (получает данные из сети), и возвращает результат. Естественно, return срабатывает раньше, чем данные получены и на выходе я получаю nil. Подскажите, как решить такую проблему?

Код у меня примерно такой:

```swift
func loadData(id: String) -> String {

var result: String?

// Здесь блок кода, который на основании id получает String параметр с сервера и присваивает его переменной result:
result = "Some string"

return result

}
```

Comment: обязательно нужно ждать? почему бы не использовать completion handler/delegate

Comment: С этим тоже не очень получается разобраться. Можете привести какой-то просто пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример, главное понять принцип как это работает

```
func loadData(id: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    session.dataTask(with: URL(string: "some_url")!) { (data, response, error) in
        // обработка error ...
        // анализ response ...
        // получаем например строку из data ...
        let str = "data_result"
        completion(str)
    }
}

loadData(id: "str") { result in
    print(result)
}
```